# javascript form submission to modify action

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, action

I'm trying to modify the post url of a form depending on the name of the file being posted. Any suggestions very much appreciated. Here is the code (which doesn't work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    function submit_form()  
    {
        document.uploadform.action = "upload?name=" + document.uploadform.codejar.value;
        return 1;
    }
</script>
<form name="uploadform" method="post" onsubmit="return submit_form();"> 
<table> 
<tr><td>Select your jar to upload</td></tr> 
<tr><td> <input type="file" name="codejar" style="width: 400"></td></tr> 
<tr><td><input type="submit" name="send" value="Upload jar"></td></tr> 
</table> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I'm trying to get it to do a plain http post of the file, to a url with the filename as a parameter"

Just do this then:

```
function submit_form()  {
    document.uploadform.action = document.uploadform.codejar.value;
    document.uploadform.submit();
}
```

...and think about changing your "send" button to

```
<button type="button" onclick='submit_form()'>Upload jar</button>
```

Comment: I think he wants to send the value from the file input.

Comment: Thanks, Steve. That's a lot closer to what I want to do. Now I get the http post where I expect with the parameters I expect. However, the actual data posted is codejar=UserServer.jar rather than the actual jar bytes. The code I'm using now is:  <script type="text/javascript"> 
function submit_form(){   document.uploadform.action = "updatecode?name=" + document.uploadform.codejar.value;   document.uploadform.submit();}
</script> 
<form name="uploadform" method="post"> ... <button type="button" onclick='submit_form()'>Upload jar</button></td></tr></table></form>

Comment: ok setting the enctype=multipart/form-data\ get the jar bytes posted, but surrounded by various text as well. is there an encoding that will just post the jar bytes?

Comment: Sorry, can't help much without your code.  But it sounds like you're on the road to success.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to do that?

You should be able to access that once the form is POSTed.

Also, browsers can send different things when getting the value from file inputs.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to do a plain http post of the file, to a url with the filename as a parameter.